# (Ubuntu Server) Is there a way to check if eth0 is working, and if not, enable wlan0?

Tags: networking, server, cron, ethernet, ifconfig

Hi I'm setting up a server that has a wireless card and an ethernet card. I'd like to have only the eth0 connection working. However, if the eth0 fails for some reason, I'd like it to turn on wlan0 and try to connect. Is there a way to do this?

I'm imagining a cron job that will every once in a while check if eth0 is connected to the router, and if this fails, it will run "sudo ifup wlan0" and then send an email to me.

But if there's a more elegant solution I'd be interested in that too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can create script in `/etc/network/if-down.d/` and in `/etc/network/if-up.d/`. Something like this. Make script called `script` with execute permissions `755`.

In example `eth0` is name of network interface

For `/etc/network/if-down.d/`

```
# Check for specific interface if desired
[ "$IFACE" != "eth0" ] || exit 0
# Do something
sudo ifup wlan0
```

For `/etc/network/if-up.d/`

```
# Check for specific interface if desired
[ "$IFACE" != "eth0" ] || exit 0
# Do something
sudo ifdown wlan0
```

Deamon will when `eth0` go down bring up `wlan0` and when `eht0` go up bring down `wlan0`

Answer (score 1):

[2707974 answer's](https://askubuntu.com/a/895279/821816) overall solution is correct, but the scripts logic are wrong: they exit when should take action, and take action when should exit;

and also we should put the script in `/etc/network/if-post-down.d/`, since according to [here](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/ifupdown/interfaces.5.en.html#HOOK_SCRIPTS) `/etc/network/if-down.d/` scripts run before the interface goes down.

the the correct answer would be:

In `/etc/network/if-post-down.d/script`

```
# Check for specific interface if desired
[ "$IFACE" = "eth0" ] || exit 0
# Do something
sudo ifup wlan0
```

in `/etc/network/if-up.d/script`

```
# Check for specific interface if desired
[ "$IFACE" = "eth0" ] || exit 0
# Do something
sudo ifdown wlan0
```

When eth0 go down bring up wlan0,
and when eht0 go up bring down wlan0